# Converting String to BigDecimal with leading zeros

Tags: java

I am trying to convert an inputstream to objects and am having trouble with converting the below string to BigDecimal. I get 87.00 as the 0's are ignored. I am experimenting with DecimalFormat. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

E.g. 0087 has to be converted to 00.87

Comment: You need to add an delimiter on which you can act later on

Comment: What is the conversion rule ? How do you know where to place the `.` ? Does it have to add or remove some  0 ? And can you show us what you've tried so far ?

Comment: Leading zeroes are not a property that `BigDecimal`s have or can represent.  Rather, they are a possible property of an *external representation*, such as in `String` form.

Comment: @vincrichaud - I would know where to place the . by using a fixed length representation from a record layout. No adding/removing 0's. Its not going to compile but I am experimenting on these lines. Object  code = "0087";
       NumberFormat nf3 = new DecimalFormat("00.00");
       System.out.println(nf3.format(code));

Comment: Ha, this seems to do the trick.. 

BigInteger d = new BigInteger("0084");
BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal(d, 2); //0.84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to indicate in comments that the initial string, `"0087"`, is a fixed-point representation with two decimal places, there therefore being an implicit decimal point before the last two digits.  There are several ways that you could convert that to a corresponding `BigDecimal`, but myself, I would go with this:

```
BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.parseLong("0087"), 2);
```

The key here is to understand that `BigDecimal`s have two characteristic properties: an arbitrary-length sequence of decimal digits, and a *scale* conveying the place value of the least-significant digit, in the form of the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.  The particular factory method demonstrated above accepts those as separate arguments, though it only works if the digit string is short enough to be represented as a `long`.  The `2` corresponds directly to the number of (implicitly) fractional digits in your input.

*Outputting* the resulting `BigDecimal` as "00.87" instead of "0.87" is a separate issue, but doable, if it's really something you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 String str="0087";
 int pos=str.lastIndexOf("0");
 String resultat=str.substring(0,pos+1);
 resultat+=".";
 resultat+=str.substring(pos+1);
 System.out.println(resultat);
 new BigDecimal(resultat);
```